# ZoomIn and ZoomOut a UIImage inside UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, zooming

I tried most of the solutions available on *StackOverflow*, but nothing worked for me.
Just wondering If anyone else can help me with this thing.

I have a `UIImage` in `UIImageview` with two buttons one for zoom in and second for zoom out. 
What I want is to zoom in or zoom out the Image not `UIImageview` when these buttons are pressed.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: You need to add your imageview in a scrollview and use scrollview zoom in/out

Comment: https://github.com/evgenyneu/ios-imagescroll

Comment: https://github.com/evgenyneu/ios-imagescroll-swift

Comment: The Problem is I have many images to show in that UIImageview with different sizes....
 @Mrunal

Comment: I updated the Question.
Hope If it make Sense. @Mrunal

Comment: UIImageView in already in UIScrollView. 
I need implementation how to make zoom work when zoom buttons are pressed. if you have any. please.... @Mrunal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88711/discussion-between-muhammad-jabbar-and-mrunal).